# Lightweight collection w/ Set contract

Tags: java, list, collections, set

I'm developing in an application requiring lots of objects in memory. One of the largest structures is of the type

```
Map<String,Set<OwnObject>> (with Set as HashSet)
```

with OwnObject being a heavyweight object representing records in a database. The application works, but has a rather large memory footprint. Reading [this](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue029.html) [Java Specialists](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/) newsletter from 2001, I've analyzed the memory usage of my large structure above. The HashSet uses a HashMap in the back, which in turn is quite a heavyweight object, and I guess this is where most of my additional memory goes.

Trying to optimize the memory usage of the structure, I tried around with multiple versions:

```
Map<String,List<OwnObject>> (with List as ArrayList)
Map<String,OwnObject[]>
```

Both work, and both are much more lean than the version using the Set<>. However, I'd like to keep the Set contract in place (uniqueness of entries).

One way would be to implement the logic myself. I could extend ArrayList and ensure the contract in add().

Are there frameworks implementing lightweight collections that honor the Set contract? Or do I miss something from the Java collections that I could use without ensuring uniqueness by myself?

Comment: if `OwnObject` is heavyweight, and if you have a lot of them in the map, then you can safely ignore `HashMap`'s overhead.

Comment: For better ease of use, you could use [guava's HashMultiMap](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap), although I doubt it will reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Sadly, it is not so. The difference in memory between the HashSet<> version and the ArrayList<> version is almost 700MB (down from 1.3GB).

Comment: That would tell me that either your object isn't really heavyweight (it may have a lot of code in it, but has a *very* small memory footprint), or that you have a lot of room to optimize the storage parameters of the `HashSet`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Good point, and "heavyweight" might be debatable. The object contains 10 members of different types (long, double, String, char), as well as multiple Lists and Maps. I'd call it heavyweight, but YMMV.

Comment: @assylias `Mulitmap` does not provide `Set` functionality and unfortunately `Multiset` is just a bag not a `Map` of `Set`

Comment: @JohnB a HashMultiMap is effectively very similar to a `HashMap<Object, HashSet<Object>>`.

Comment: @assylias I stand corrected. I had missed the following statement: `The multimap does not store duplicate key-value pairs. Adding a new key-value pair equal to an existing key-value pair has no effect.`

Comment: If HashMap/Set is using much more memory than ArrayList containing the same objects then it is the indexing mechanism that is the cause which is a side-effect solely of the **number** of elements in the set. There are other structures that can reduce this such as TrieSet/Map but that relies on encoding the keys in a more compact manner. Essentially - if you really need to get away from O(n) presence test/lookup then you have to pay the cost.

Comment: Do you need to be able to modify the set?  Guava's `ImmutableSet` is significantly more memory-efficient than `HashSet` (see [this](https://code.google.com/p/memory-measurer/wiki/ElementCostInDataStructures))

Comment: The set needs to be modifiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I implemented is the following:

```
Map<String,OwnObject[]>
```

Adding and removing to the array was done using Arrays.binarySearch() and 2 slice System.arraysCopy()s, by which sorting and uniqueness happen on the side.